# Netbeans Profiler throwing - saved calibration data file does not exist error

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, profiler

I am getting this error message saved calibration data file does not exist even after doing calibration on the remote tomcat server? Does anyone have any clue..

Answer (score 1):

You probably ran calibration with one user, and the application to profile with a different user. Check Netbeans bug [154300](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=154300). Newer Netbeans versions will show where calibration expects the file to be.